# Override methods when altering parameters

Tags: c#, string, tostring

Do I still need to use the `override` keyword when I've altered / added parameters to the method?

For example, I would override ToString() as follows:

```
public override ToString()
{
  // Implementation details
}
```

However, do I need to use `override` if I also have the following overloaded example:

```
public override ToString(String header)
{
  // Implementation details including use of header parameter
}
```

In fact, is it even advisable to do this within ToString() ? Or should I keep ToString() free from parameter dependence?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Come on, just try it and see.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of ToString overloads which accept parameters in the .NET framework; don't worry about that. Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb.aspx

Comment: I would just point out that running the code doesn't answer whether it breaks the OO model, and I wasn't aware that .NET already includes such overloaded examples. Thank you for the replies

Comment: `whether it breaks the OO model`  models are just paths of best practices, not rules (and it is very subjective topic). `I wasn't aware that .NET already includes such overloaded`  Just compile it. You will get an error if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not. That is an overload, not an override, so putting in the `override` will cause a compilation error since a method with a matching signature could be not found to override.

An override is used to override a virtual method on a parent class. The signature of the method must match: the parameters, return type, etc. Section 1.6.6.4 has more details in the C# specification.

Comment: Thanks - and would you care to say if it's inappropriate to overload ToString() in such a way? I can't help but feel that ToString() should just represent the object, and not be muddled with parameter inclusion

Comment: @Jack that's a matter of opinion, however on the surface it doesn't sound bad. That case certainly exists elsewhere in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you for your replies - although the consensus is that I should have just run the code, the main crux of my question was about the best practice point which I thought I'd put to my betters. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

No you haven't to override the `ToString(String header)`, because the `System.Object`, which is the base object of all the types in .NET doesn't contain such a method. On the other hand, it has a virtual method called `ToString`, which doesn't take any parameter.

That you want is to have a method with the same name and different signature. This is called method overloading.